# nested if vs loop condition

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++

I have to do a comparison and I want to know which will be faster.

1)

```
  for (i=0;i<4;i++){
     if (object1(i)==object2(i))
          retval = true;
     else { 
          retval = false;
          break;
     }
}
```

2)

```
 if ( (object1(0)==object2(0) && (object1(1)==object2(1) && (object1(2)==object2(2) && (object1(3)==object2(3)){
      retval = true;
 else
      retval = false;
```

Or both will perform the same?
Thanks for Advice

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: are you sure that you are more concerned about the performance improvement in a for loop rather than readability? If you are then i suspect the whole project is an ideal candidate for refactoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking the most efficient path would be:

```
retval = object1(0) == object2(0) && object1(1) == object2(1).....
```

This basically does the same as your loop, but doesn't have to compare the result to `true` to determine the outcome of the condition.

However, I strongly recommend keeping the loop, as it is far easier to adapt to add or remove numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If the optimization flags are on, then the compiler might produce same machine instructtions for both code, unlooping the `for` loop completely, as the exact number of iteration is known to the compiler:

- [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)

By the way, if you care so much, then you could write this:

```
bool retValue = (object1(0)==object2(0)) && 
                (object1(1)==object2(1)) && 
                (object1(2)==object2(2)) && 
                (object1(3)==object2(3));
```

which avoids both: `for` loop, as well as `if-else` branch, and it doesn't depend on compiler optimization.

Comment: You have unmatched (and unnecessary) opening parentheses …

Comment: Hmm, I’d just have removed them. They don’t really help here at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to measure. But in any case the first code can be simplified quite a bit:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    if (object1(i) != object2(i))
        return false;

return true;
```

Now choose the more readable form. I’d choose the loop here, unless you have confirmed that there is a performance problem caused by this code.

Answer (score 0):

As always with optimization, the one and single rule is **MEASURE**.

Furthermore, I guess that the compiler could optimize this code in some ways you (and I) couldn't even imagine. Therefore I'd suggest to write it in the most *readable* form.

Comment: version 2 also leads to stop comparing objects as soon as one comparison is false.

Answer (score 0):

I like to play with the Try out LLVM and Clang page for this:

```
struct Object {
  int operator()(int i) const;
};

bool loop(Object const& left, Object const& right) {
  bool retval = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     if (left(i) == right(i) )
          retval = true;
     else { 
          retval = false;
          break;
     }
  }
  return true;
}

bool inlineif(Object const& left, Object const& right) {
  bool retval = true;
  if ( left(0) == right(0) &&
       left(1) == right(1) &&
       left(2) == right(2) &&
       left(3) == right(3))
      retval = true;
  else
      retval = false;
  return retval;
}

bool betterloop(Object const& left, Object const& right) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    if (left(i) != right(i))
        return false;

  return true;
}

bool betterif(Object const& left, Object const& right) {
  return left(0) == right(0) &&
         left(1) == right(1) &&
         left(2) == right(2) &&
         left(3) == right(3);
}
```

Produces the following IR for loops (regardless of how they are written):

```
define zeroext i1 @_Z4loopRK6ObjectS1_(%struct.Object* %left, %struct.Object* %right) uwtable {
  br label %1

; <label>:1                                       ; preds = %7, %0
  %i.0 = phi i32 [ 0, %0 ], [ %8, %7 ]
  %2 = icmp slt i32 %i.0, 4
  br i1 %2, label %3, label %9

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %1
  %4 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %left, i32 %i.0)
  %5 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %right, i32 %i.0)
  %6 = icmp eq i32 %4, %5
  br i1 %6, label %7, label %9

; <label>:7                                       ; preds = %3
  %8 = add nsw i32 %i.0, 1
  br label %1

; <label>:9                                       ; preds = %3, %1
  ret i1 true
}
```

And a very similar IR for the two if (so I'll give only one):

```
define zeroext i1 @_Z8betterifRK6ObjectS1_(%struct.Object* %left, %struct.Object* %right) uwtable {
  %1 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %left, i32 0)
  %2 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %right, i32 0)
  %3 = icmp eq i32 %1, %2
  br i1 %3, label %4, label %16

; <label>:4                                       ; preds = %0
  %5 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %left, i32 1)
  %6 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %right, i32 1)
  %7 = icmp eq i32 %5, %6
  br i1 %7, label %8, label %16

; <label>:8                                       ; preds = %4
  %9 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %left, i32 2)
  %10 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %right, i32 2)
  %11 = icmp eq i32 %9, %10
  br i1 %11, label %12, label %16

; <label>:12                                      ; preds = %8
  %13 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %left, i32 3)
  %14 = tail call i32 @_ZNK6ObjectclEi(%struct.Object* %right, i32 3)
  %15 = icmp eq i32 %13, %14
  br label %16

; <label>:16                                      ; preds = %12, %8, %4, %0
  %17 = phi i1 [ false, %8 ], [ false, %4 ], [ false, %0 ], [ %15, %12 ]
  ret i1 %17
}
```

The important instructions here is `br` which is the branching instruction. It can be used either as a simple `goto` or with conditions on the edges:

```
br i1 %11, label %12, label %16
```

means if `i1` is true, go to `label %12`, otherwise go to `label %16`.

It seems that "naturally" LLVM will not unroll the traditional loop version, so the `if` version performs better here. I am quite surprised, actually, that it does not and I cannot figure out why it would not...

So, the inline if code *might* be a bit faster, but it might also be unnoticeable depending on the cost of `left(i) == right(i)` (and even then), as CPU are quite good at branch prediction.